# How to check whether column names and data associated with it matches or not in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Suppose I have few columns as below:

```
EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, EMP_CONTACT  
1, SIDDHESH, 544949461
```

Now I want to validate whether data is in sync with the column names schema. For `EMP_NAME` data in that column should be `string` only. I tried below code after referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46136715/field-data-validation-using-spark-dataframe/46139584) link but it shows an error on the last line of my code.

```
package com.sample
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
class sample1 {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  val data = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("C:/Users/siddheshk2/Desktop/words.txt")
  val originalSchema = data.schema

  def validateColumns(row: Row): Row = {
    val emp_id = row.getAs[String]("EMP_ID")
    val emp_name = row.getAs[String]("EMP_NAME")
    val emp_contact = row.getAs[String]("EMP_CONTACT")

    // do checking here and populate (err_col,err_val,err_desc) with values if applicable

    Row.merge(row)
  }
  val validateDF = data.map { row => validateColumns(row) }

}
```

So, it doesn't accept the last line of my code `val validateDF = data.map { row => validateColumns(row) }`. How do I solve this? Or is there any other effective way of solving my problem?

I entered an invalid record (3rd one) like below:

```
EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,EMP_CONTACT
1,SIDDHESH,99009809
2,asdadsa, null
sidh,sidjh,1232
```

In this case, I have had entered a `string` value for the `id` column (which should be a number) so after checking column schema with its data it should throw an error saying that the record doesn't match as per column schema.

Comment: You can always add a schema or infer the schema from the file when reading the data. Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926411/provide-schema-while-reading-csv-file-as-a-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

You just missed to convert your DataFrame to rdd in order to apply `.map` operation try this instead :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row    
val validateDF = data.rdd.map { row => validateColumns(row) }
```

And if you want to convert it back to DataFrame, just use your sparkSession for that:

```
val newSchema = // specify the schema of the new dataframe
val updatedDF = spark.createDataFrame(validateDF, newSchema)
```

Comment: But how do I check whether data is according to the schema specified or not?

Comment: Instead of creating a new dataframe it would be better if I can check and discard the rows or entire data. So, how can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

Row class has a [schema](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/b2a74107d50a0f69d727049581e01d9e2f6b4778/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.scala#L152) property. You can use it by iterating through the columns and comparing them. For that you can use the `==` operator or use one the schema comparison methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47862974/schema-comparison-of-two-dataframes-in-scala).

The validate method then could look as next:

```
def isValid(row: Row): Boolean = originalSchema == row.schema
```

Comment: How do I handle this or implement this? Check my edited post

Comment: How do I merge this in my code? I am new to scala as well so, not sure.

Comment: Spark will try to infer the schema from the data itself. In your example the whole EMP_ID will be converted to string since Spark sees that there is a string. This will happen if you haven't specified the schema, alternatively you can specify the schema explicitly. If you define EMP_ID as int Spark would have failed to load the data. To sum up you don't need any validation function as the one above if you specify the correct schema